# what this error means The model backing the 'OdeToFoodDb' context has changed since the database was created?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have added a column to my existing db table and suddenly the MVC app stopped working with the error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The model backing the 'OdeToFoodDb' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing
>   the 'OdeToFoodDb' context has changed since the database was created.
>   Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 28:             //                  }; Line 29:  Line 30:
>   var restaurants = _db.Restaurants Line 31:
>   .OrderByDescending(r => r.Reviews.Average(rv => rv.Rating)) Line 32:
>   .Where( r=>searchTerm == null || r.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm) )

why this happens, and how do i fix this, especially is there away to fix this not using code first approach?

Comment: Hey @Phill - did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means one of your Models (classes which the Code-First turns into actual tables in your database) has changed.

This can be a change on one of the fields, like adding a key attribute, or adding a new field to the Model.

If you don't remember any change you've done, you can activate an `Update-Database` command (if `Automatic Migrations` is turned on, which is the default behavior) with the `Verbose` keyword. This would detail the changes made, while updating your actual databse.

This command is run on the `Package Manager Console` inside visual studio.

**Like this:**

```
Update-database -verbose
```

BTW, I see no way to fix this unless using the code-first approach.

The only thing I can think of, is to un-map some fields, that you want in the model, but not in the database. This way EF won't complain on the model change.
This can be achieved using the `NotMapped` attribute, placed on top of the specified field.